# Customizing the page numbers to show in pagination using jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and I am implementing my custom server-side processing for loading the table records. By default, my api returns 20 records at one time and let's assume the total records are 200 and I am showing 10 records per page(this is fixed).
Now my problem is since initially only 20 records are loaded in the table and i am 10 rows per page, the pagination only shows two page numbers 1 and 2. But i want to show all the possible page numbers which will be 20 (200/10).
so is there any way i can set the value for no of pages i want to show or any other way to achieve this?

P.S. In my api I am getting the total no of records so that's not a problem. I just can't figure out how to set the value for page numbers.

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this issue ? I am trying to figure out same problem, how to update total records after my custom processing.

Comment: No, Made a workaround by sending 50 records from the api and thus I was able to show "5" page numbers initially.

Answer (score 0):

Set recordsTotal and recordsFiltered to 200 for response and length to 10 for request.
You don't need to have API return 20 it can return 10 (your page size) for each call. DataTable take care to populate the table with this size.

Comment: As I mentioned I am not using the default server-side processing of  jquery datatable, I am using my custom implementation for getting records. Is there any way i can manually set these paramaters?

Comment: What do you mean by "not using the default server-side processing"? Can you post the code for table initialization with AJAX call and your "ustom implementation for getting records"?